# Difficulty Changing Text Color in FreeType and OpenGL Rendering

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, glfw, ftgl

I'm currently facing challenges in changing the text color when rendering text using FTGL and OpenGL. Despite efforts to set the text color, the rendered text appears to be in a default color (red). I've tried adjusting the color parameters, but the results remain unchanged.

I've tried changing

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);
```

To the following and setting the following for the color

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Here is the full code and also my rendering window. Thanks in advance!

```
void CreateTransparentWindow() {

    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        obs_log(LOG_INFO, "GlfwInit failed to initilize.");
        return false;
    }

    // Set window hints for borderless and transparent window
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE);

    // 4x antialiasing - Makes things look sharper.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    
    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1919, 1079, "Qt281QWindowIcon", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        obs_log(LOG_INFO, "Failed to create window.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }

    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set up the projection matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1919, 1079, 0, -1, 1); // Custom coordinates

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE); // Anti antialiasing

    //Initilize FT Libary and Text Attributes.
    FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
    FT_New_Face(ft, "C:\\Users\\Joel\\Desktop\\Roboto-Regular.ttf", 0, &face);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Get the HWND of the GLFW window
    HWND hwnd = glfwGetWin32Window(window);

    // Set the window to be click-through
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);

    // Set the layered attribute to enable transparency
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);

    // Make the window always on top
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    // Set V-Sync to 1 (enabled)
    glfwSwapInterval(0);

    return true;

}

void DrawTextGL(int x, int y, int size, const char *text, COLORREF color)
{
    // Set font size and color
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, size);

    // Create and bind texture outside the loop
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    // Set texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    for (const char *c = text; *c; ++c) {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, *c, FT_LOAD_RENDER) != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Copy glyph bitmap to texture
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);

        // Calculate texture coordinates
        float tx1 = x + face->glyph->bitmap_left;
        float ty1 = y - face->glyph->bitmap_top;
        float tx2 = tx1 + face->glyph->bitmap.width;
        float ty2 = ty1 + face->glyph->bitmap.rows;

        // Render textured quad
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(tx1, ty1);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(tx2, ty1);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(tx2, ty2);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(tx1, ty2);
        glEnd();

        // Advance position
        x += (face->glyph->advance.x >> 6);
        y += (face->glyph->advance.y >> 6);
    }

    // Clean up: delete texture after the loop
    glDeleteTextures(1, &textureID);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without shaders, `GL_RED` won't do what you want, as if fixes G/B/A channels as 0/0/1.  Programmable shaders will let you repurpose the channel, but it appears you are using legacy OpenGL, which doesn't offer you that.

To do what you want without programmable shaders, one solution is to change to using RGBA (or RGB), as you have begun doing.  However, you will *also* need to take the single 8-bit channel data in `face->glyph->bitmap.buffer` and build a new RGBA buffer.  You can then pass the RGBA buffer into `glTexImage2D` instead.

Edit: If you don't mind the background of the text forced to black, you could alternately use *internal format* `GL_RGBA`, and *format* `GL_LUMINANCE`.  This puts the value from the 8-bit source channel into each of the three color channels R/G/B and 1.0 in the alpha channel... in other words: opaque grayscale.  (I thought `GL_INTENSITY` was supposed to copy it to all four channels, but it did not seem to work when I tested it.)
If you run `glPixelTransferf()` on `GL_RED_SCALE`, `GL_GREEN_SCALE`, and `GL_BLUE_SCALE` before `glTexImage2D()`, you can change from grayscale to shades of another color.

Edit 2: Similarly, you can create a black texture with alpha-mask using `GL_RGBA`/`GL_ALPHA`.  The color can be adjusted to another color by setting `GL_RED_BIAS`, `GL_GREEN_BIAS`, and `GL_BLUE_BIAS` using `glPixelTransferf()` ahead of time.  It'd also probably a good idea to set these back to 0 once you're done loading the glyph textures.

Comment: Since there weren't sufficent solutions for what I wanted (without using shaders) I switched my renderer window to d2d along with sdl2 for rendering objects/text.